# Always got that error under Yosemite: <Error>: ImageIO: CGImageSourceCreateWithData data parameter is nil

Tags: macos, mapkit, osx-yosemite

Good morning team.
I'm using a mkmapview under Yosemite and render custom tiles. But always got that error :
: ImageIO: CGImageSourceCreateWithData data parameter is nil

Although the tiles are drawn successfully.
I searched a lot and tried everything I faced.

1. Change map types.
2. Change the flag: canReplaceMapContent.
3. Change the project to non-ARC and retain all objects.

I even get a code from [github](https://github.com/viggiosoft/MapTileOverlayTutorial) & it produces the same error
Nothing succedded. Is that a bug in the system? If not how can I overcome it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a current iOS 8 bug in `MKTileOverlayRenderer`. I have been working on this over in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/mapbox/mbxmapkit/issues/132) and have produced [an alternate renderer class](https://github.com/mapbox/mbxmapkit/blob/132-renderer/MBXMapKit/MBXRasterTileRenderer.m). Not tested on OS X, but should be minor to no change to port it there. I'm guessing the same bug exists in both platforms.

Comment: hi, I try to use your renderer but have a great performance issues - the memory is growing up to gigabytes and the tiles are loading continuously even if I don't touch the map. How can I solve this?